# Is it possible to make a setOnClickListener block wait on a method call inside it?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a method call first thing inside a `setOnClickListener` block that gets some value from an API which I use to start a live stream, it's critical for that method call, to finish before anything else is done inside the block in order to get the correct result because everything else after that first line method call is dependent on that.

Code snippet:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {

            // Everything depends on check stream call
            currentViewModel.checkStream()

            if (!PlaybackService.isServiceStarted) {
                if (isStreaming!!) {
                    onPlayerStart()
                    sliding_player.panelState = SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED
                } else
                    Snackbar.make(appbar, R.string.stream_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

I need for the `myButton.setOnClickListener` block to wait on
 `currentViewModel.checkStream()` in order for the following lines to work correctly (give the correct result).

Is it possible to do that? Using some sort of callback method? Should I consider doing that with Retrofit2?

Comment: You must have to define the code after your API call success.

Answer (score 2):

You should never wait on the main thread and `onClick()` is called on the main thread.

You could consider an asynchronous framework to handle your use-case. These frameworks would include *RxJava*, `AsyncTask` or even plain `Handler` implementations. To be nearer to your actual implementation, *Kotlin Coroutines* might be most suitable, as switching back to the main thread is very clear. It also integrates well with *Retrofit*.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // make sure checkStream() is a suspending function
        // to wait for it execution to finish
        currentViewModel.checkStream()

        if (!PlaybackService.isServiceStarted) {
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if (isStreaming!!) {
                    onPlayerStart()
                    sliding_player.panelState = COLLAPSED
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(appbar, R.string.stream_fail, LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `coroutineScope` you'd have to attach to the lifecycle to not leak the activity or fragment.

Comment: This works kind of, but I'm always getting the correct result the second time I press the button because the method always gets the default value for `isStreaming` which is false which is not correct.

Comment: I'd assume you're just not waiting for `currentViewModel.checkStream()` to complete. Since you didn't add the code, I cannot really tell you anything about it. If it's an asynchronous call, make sure to suspend it until it's finished. Also it might be possible that `isStreaming` is set too late and you actually run into a race condition somehow.

Comment: is it possible to wait for checkstream()?

Comment: It is. But I don't know what `checkStream()` is or does. Implement it as a suspending function. Depending on the actual calls within there, you might have serveral options to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first call api then get response to call your method like this way..

```
Call<UploadObject> fileUpload = uploadImage.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename);
        fileUpload.enqueue(new Callback<UploadObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UploadObject> call, Response<UploadObject> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "Success " + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "Success " + response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UploadObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

make your network call inside asycn class
and use as below mentioned code

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    //start asycn call from here
    // new Async().execute();
        }

class Async extends Async{
    onPreExecute(){}

    doInBackground(){
        // below method call should be synchronised
        currentViewModel.checkStream()
    }

    onPostExecute(){
        if (!PlaybackService.isServiceStarted) {
                if (isStreaming!!) {
                    onPlayerStart()
                    sliding_player.panelState = SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED
                } else
                    Snackbar.make(appbar, R.string.stream_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible if you call your API in on main thread but it will stuck your UI. So the best way is to call your API in Asynchronous way and execute you further code once API return success.

Check below AsyncTask call.

```
public class AsyncUploadStream extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public AsyncUploadStream() {   
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        return currentViewModel.checkStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();

        try {

            if (!PlaybackService.isServiceStarted) {
                if (isStreaming !!){
                    onPlayerStart()
                    sliding_player.panelState = SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED
                } else{
                    Snackbar.make(appbar, R.string.stream_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```